# How does GAE Search Api SortOptions work?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-search-api

I am a little lost on how [SortOptions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/search/options#Java_SortOptions) work.

Say my query is

```
Query query = Query.newBuilder()
                .setOptions(QueryOptions.newBuilder().setLimit(RESULT_SIZE).setReturningIdsOnly(true).setSortOptions(sortOptions).build())
                .build(queryText);//RESULT_SIZE=300
```

Now say I have 4000 documents or so and I want to grab the latest documents only. Does it first grab 300 documents and then sort them? Or does it sort all the 4000 documents and then return the 300 latest documents? Assuming of course I am doing

```
SortOptions sortOptions = SortOptions.newBuilder()
    .addSortExpression(SortExpression.newBuilder()
        .setExpression("date")
        .setDirection(SortExpression.SortDirection.DESCENDING)
        .setLimit(RESULT_SIZE)//RESULT_SIZE=300
    .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to grab as many as possible by the SortOptions limit, the limit is 10,000, which are then sorted and the QueryOptions limit is applied.